# How do I launch an EC2 instance and have it be instance-backed and not EBS-backed?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to launch an EC2 instance and have it be instance (ephemeral storage) backed and not EBS backed. It is not clear that I can do this through the AWS console (as of 5/2013).

Can someone please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see is to select an AMI that uses Instance Store for it's root device. It should be specified in the AMI description if it uses EBS or Instance Store for the root device.